# Sharing A Mutual Friend

Tags: facebook

A Facebook user lists a mutual friend we both share, however when I check the mutual friends friend list, that persons name does not appear. Why is that?

Comment: This is a bit of a reach, but is it possible it's a different account, but with the same name and picture? Click on it in the friends list to make sure.